# number theory closure property

Tags: number-theory

Consider the set of all numbers less than $n$ and relatively prime to it. Let $S = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_{φ(n)}\}$ be this set.

How to prove that if $a \in S$ and $b \in S$, then $ab \pmod n \in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that $ab (\pmod{n})$ is not relatively prime to $n$.

Pick a prime $p$ which divides $ab \pmod{n}$ and $n$. Show that $p$ divides $ab$, which means....

Comment: If $gcd(ab, n) = 1$, then how can I deduce that $ab \pmod n \in S$?

Comment: @nitrogen I told you in my answer. proof by contradiction....

Answer (score 0):

I was just confused. What I needed to prove was, 
$$gcd(ab \pmod n, n) = 1$$
Given that, $gcd(ab, n) = 1$.

The proof directly follows from Euclid's theorem, 
$$gcd(x, y) = gcd(y, x \pmod y)$$
Thus, $gcd(ab, n) = gcd(n, ab \pmod n)$.
Also, $1 \leq ab \pmod n \lt n$ and we also have that $ab \pmod n$ and $n$ are coprime. Thus $ab \pmod n \in S$.